# Oracle SQL Split Row Into Multiple Entries Based on Start and End

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand if it is possible to create an Oracle SQL VIEW (e.g. no function/procedure) which splits the following into different rows based on the start and end

E.g.

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| user | start_num | end_num |
+------+-----------+---------+
| Bob  |        87 |      98 |
| Sue  |        55 |      64 |
+------+-----------+---------+
```

Example result:

```
+------+-----+
| User | num |
+------+-----+
| Bob  |  87 |
| Bob  |  88 |
| Bob  |  89 |
| Bob  |  90 |
| Bob  |  91 |
| Bob  |  92 |
| Bob  |  93 |
| Bob  |  94 |
| Bob  |  95 |
| Bob  |  95 |
| Bob  |  96 |
| Bob  |  97 |
| Bob  |  98 |
| Sue  |  55 |
| Sue  |  56 |
| Sue  |  57 |
| Sue  |  58 |
| Sue  |  59 |
| Sue  |  60 |
| Sue  |  61 |
| Sue  |  62 |
| Sue  |  63 |
| Sue  |  64 |
+------+-----+
```

I've been looking at CONNECT BY LEVEL examples of creating a running number sequence - but struggling to understand if it will work. And maybe there is a much simpler way which I have overlooked?

Sample SQL to create initial data:

```
with tab1 as
     (select 'Bob' "user",87 "start_num", 98 "end_num" from dual
     union
     select 'Sue' "user",55 "start_num", 64 "end_num" from dual)
select * from tab1
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle you use ? Just as info , If >12c there is just way to use `lateral` to generate the same what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with tab1 as (
      select 'Bob' as usr, 87 as start_num, 98 as end_num from dual
      union all
      select 'Sue' as usr, 55 as start_num, 64 as end_num from dual
     ),
     cte (usr, num, end_num) as (
      select usr, start_num, end_num
      from tab1
      union all
      select user, num + 1, end_num
      from cte
      where num < end_num
     )
select usr, num
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7f4c9168d1547e4bfe0610d6f2753de) is a db<>fiddle.